# How to get jQuery to receive ill-formed JSON via cross-domain request?

Tags: json, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm making a request to an old server that serves up ill-formed JSON. It's not mine, so I can't modify the server. It's cross-domain. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://someDomain.com/getData.htm',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Got an error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Got it: " + data);
    }
});
```

As it stands, of course, I get:

```
Got an error: parseerror Jquery12379789584794587_2893798579279874978 was not called.
```

So it's choking because the JSON-esque response looks like this:

```
{name:"RMA-83186",date:"01/24/12 13:30:45"}
```

...and jQuery rightfully requires it to be well-formed JSON. (It's not because the properties should be double-quoted. See the "Important" note [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).)

So, I thought I'd bring the response in as `dataType: 'text'`, clean it up and then let jQuery parse it as JSON. However, when I change it to `dataType: 'text'` I get:

```
Got an error: error No transport
```

...which is what you get from a cross-domain request. I tried adding `crossDomain: true` to the request and using it with the `text` dataType, but got the same error.

Anyone know how I can get this ill-formed data in from a cross-domain request so I can clean and parse it?

Thanks!

EDIT: The `dataFilter` parm doesn't help because the root problem (when using `dataType:'jsonp'`) is not even the ill-formed JSON string, but rather that the response is not a true JSONp response, i.e., it's not a function call.

Comment: I won't add this as an answer to your question since your question is about jQuery.  But, to solve your issue, have a look at my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2PLb6/1/  Plug in your URL and see if it works for you.  We've used this manual method in the past to get around the problem

Comment: @Brent, thanks for that, but the problem turns out to be that not only is the JSON ill-formed, but it's also not returned in a true JSONp format, which would be a function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only suggestion I think would work would be to use an intermediary server side proxy that you control. This way you can format the data correctly and feed it back to your JavaScript. You could also use a [Yahoo! Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com).

The problem is that a JSONP call is really just a new script element added to the DOM. And you can't request plain text because of the same origin policy. Also, since the server doesn't return proper JSON, I'm sure it won't work with a [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) request. Therefore, you will have to use the proxy.